# passing custom object as parameter to a webmethod of asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, service

I have a custom class declared as follows (in vb.net)

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class NumInfo 
    Public n As String     
    Public f As Integer     
    Public fc As char()     
    Public t As Integer     
    Public tc As char()     
    Private validFlag As Boolean = True    

    Public Sub New()    
    End Sub 
    'I also have public properties(read/write) for all the public variables

End Class
```

In my service.asmx codebehind class I have a webmethod as follows:

```
  Public Function ConvertTo(ByVal info As NumInfo) As String        
      Return mbc(info)<br>'mbc is another function defined in my service.asmx "service" class
  End Function
```

**The problem is that when I start debugging it to test it, the page that I get does not contain any fields where I could input the values for the public fields of numInfo. How do I initialise the class?** There is no "Invoke" button either. All I see are soap details as below:

> **ConvertTo**
> **Test**
> The test form is only
>   available for methods with primitive
>   types as parameters.
> **SOAP 1.1**
> The
>   following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request
>   and response. The
>  placeholders
>   shown need to be replaced with actual
>   values.
> POST **/Converter/BC.asmx**
>   
> **HTTP/1.1**
> Host:
>   **localhost**
> Content-Type: **text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8**
> Content-Length:
>   **length**
> SOAPAction:
>   **"http://Services/ConvertTo"**
> <?xml
>   version="1.0"
>   encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <soap:Envelope
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <soap:Body>
>       <ConvertTo xmlns="http://Services/">
>         <info>
>           <n>string</n>
>           <f>int&lt/f> 
>           <fc>
>             <char>char</char>
>             <char>char>/char>
>           </fc>
> ..etc..

What am I doing wrong? **For the record I tried replacing char() with string to see if it was the array causing problems but that didn't help either**. I'm fairly new to web services. I tried replacing the custom object parameter with a primitive parameter just to check how things worked and it rendered a page with an input field and invoke button. I just can't seem to get it working with custom object. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the message says "The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters." meaning string, bool, int etc.

I find it is simple enough to set up a test page where I can define my object and pass it to the web method for debugging purposes.

Comment: lol..thanks Senloe. I can't believe I've been blind and stupid enough to not see it!! :D. I've already posted this question on a hundred forums by now and wasted a whole day thinking I must be doing something wrong!! :D THANKS A TON!